# Are 'safe_value' values generated dynamically from the 'value' value?

Tags: 7

I'm changing the content of an HTML field using `entity_metadata_wrapper`, and I see 3 values, like `value`, `format`, and `safe_value`.

My question is if I have to also edit `safe_value` or it will be generated dynamically. Thanks

PS: I edited and saved only `value` then in next load, the other were empty. I went to the node and clicked `Save` and the safe value was regenerated. Maybe I should call a hook after editing value?
Currently I'm using the `check_markup` function to generate the `safe_value` from the modified `value`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `safe_value` is derived from `value`; `safe_value` contains the results of [`_text_sanitize()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21text%21text.module/function/_text_sanitize/7.x) after it applies all the filters you've set on your text field.

It isn't set after a node save; it's set on a field load; the field module loads it via [`hook_field_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21text%21text.module/function/text_field_load/7.x) with its [`text_field_load()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21modules%21text%21text.module/function/text_field_load/7.x) invocation.